# How can I standardize shell script header #! on different hosts?

Tags: shell

I manage a large number of shell (ksh) scripts on server A. Each script begins with the line...

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
```

When I deploy to machine B, C, and D I frequently need to use a different shell such as /bin/ksh, /usr/local/bin/ksh or even /usr/dt/bin/ksh. Assume I am unable to install a new version of ksh and I am unable to create links in any protected directories such as /usr/local/bin. At the moment I have a sed script which modifies all the scripts but I would prefer not to do this. I would like to standardize the header so that it no longer needs to be changed from server to server. I don't mind using something like

```
#!~/ksh
```

And creating a link which is on every server but I have had problems with finding home using "~" in the past when using rsh (maybe is was ssh) to call a script (AIX specifically I think). Another option might be to create a link in my home directory and ensuring that it is first in my PATH, and simply using

```
#!ksh
```

Looking for a good solution. Thanks.

Update 8/26/11 - Here is the solution I came up with. The installation script looks for the various versions of ksh installed on the server and then copies one of the ksh 93 programs to /tmp/ksh93. The scripts in the framework all refer to #!/tmp/ksh93 and they don't need to be changed from one server to the other. The script also set some variables so that if the file is every removed from /tmp, it will immediately be put back the next time a scheduled task runs, which is at a minimum every minute.

Comment: Putting anything permanent in `/tmp` is ... very unorthodox, not to mention liable to failure unless you arrange for the file to be recreated on reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rettops noted, you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
```

This will likely work for you. However, there can be some drawbacks. See [Wikipedia on Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability) for a fairly thorough discussion.

Comment: OK thanks. The Wikipedia article was helpful, I see this is not a "solved" problem. I have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env ksh
```

will use whatever ksh is in the user's path.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the default path when the script is called from cron? .profile is not read at this point, in many cases the wrong ksh is in my default path

Comment: @Ethan Post: In the crontab, as the command, try `PATH=... /path/to/command args ...`.